# Get folder names and file names from sharepoint list to excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I want to get list of folder names and files in it from sharepoint list to excel and excel will be updated automatically. I am having access problem using Power Query so power query is out.

I found out a way is to get sharepoint folder link and somehow, excel able to get folder and file names from the folder link, but how?

Please share with me the method above or if you have any better way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used in the past to get an export of a document library to excel

```
http://url.to.site\_vti_bin\owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Using=_layouts\fquery.iqy&List={listguid}
```

For example, if you have a list with guid {A2EF22BC-EE76-48F8-AD27-73BEC55A7D4B}, you would url encode the braces and dashes and end up with a url like this

```
http://url.to.site\_vti_bin\owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Using=_layouts\fquery.iqy&List=%7BA2EF22BC%2DEE76%2D48F8%2DAD27%2D73BEC55A7D4B%7D
```